# python: output a list to a csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I am trying to write `my_list` to a csv file like below:

```
import csv

myfile = open('my_list.csv', 'w')
wr = csv.writer(myfile)
print(len(my_list))
wr.writerow(my_list)
```

`my_list` has length 1000. Then the output of the above code is:

```
1000
10001
```

The output `my_list.csv` looks fine. But I am wondering why it print out `10001` on the screen? What does it mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are doing this in the Python console. When you print `len(my_list)`, it will print 1000. Next, you use `wr.writerow()`. It will write the row to the file and then return the current position in the file. Since it just wrote 1000 lines, the file position is at 1001 so that the next line written will not overwrite anything. In the Python console, the value that is returned is printed. If you were to execute a file with the same script, you wouldn't see that number.